# Which is the longest River in Germany and Russia?

Tags: geography, rivers

Danube is 2850 km long and yet Rhine (1233 km) is considered the longest River in Germany.

Likewise,the confusion between Yenisei and Volga in Russia.

Comment: Both Danube and Rhine flow thorugh many countries, can form borders between countries and thus belong to both. Rhine is forked in its upper part and its delta is complex. Danube source is set per definition (politics *rolleyes*) and it disappears and reappears in a karstic environment. Longest river with course through Germany would be the Rhine, followed by the Elbe.

Comment: @a_donda Right. So does that logic apply to Russian Rivers as well? Volga is the longest because Yenisei flows through other countries too?